# jQuery count value plus one by every reload

Tags: jquery, function, count, numbers, reload

I'm stuck. Every time I get `NaN`.

I'm trying to load this function over and over again to check various pages and the value nowp has to count +1 by every ajax success. But nopw is `NaN` and I don't know why it does that. Can somebody help me?

It has to begin with 21 and ending with 1346.

```js
function loadedt() {

        var from = 21;
        var till = 1346;
        
        if(typeof(nowp) != "undefined" && nowp !== null) {
            var nowp = Math.ceil(from);
        } else {
            if(nowp == till) {
                var nowp = 'finish';
            } else {
                //Here nowp need to cont plus 1
                nowp++;
            }
            
        }
        
        //nowp++;
        
        console.log(nowp);
        
        $('#uitslag').html('Wait a minute..');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '<?php echo $website['adres']; ?>/get/pet.php', 
            data: { 
                pa : nowp
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                
                if(nowp == 'finish') {
                    $('#uitslag').fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $('#uitslag').html('ýes '+nowp+' and '+data).fadeIn(500).delay(500);
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#uitslag').fadeOut(500, function() {
                        $('#uitslag').html('page '+nowp+' and '+data).fadeIn(4000, function() {
                            //nowp++;
                            loadedt();
                            
                        }).delay(3000);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }$(document).ready(loadedt);
```

Comment: Save the variable in `localStorage` and restore it when the page loads.

Comment: NaN. NuNs are exclusive to cloisters.

Comment: `loadedt` just adds an event handler to `document.ready`, it doesn't actually run that code. I suggest changing it to `function loadedt() { var from = 21; /* everything else currently in $(document).ready(function() { ... }); */ } $(document).ready(loadedt);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I need is that with every reload that nowp adds +1. I want to fetch page pet.php?pa=21 via ajax then pet.php?pa=22 ect...

I've updated the code after Heretic Monkey's answer